# HashMap of HashMaps traversal

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap, traversal

In Java, I'm trying to retrieve a `HashMap<String, Object>` that has the Object which is: `HashMap<String, Object>`.

I implemented a recursive function that returns either the `HashMap<String, Object>` found with the given key, or `null` if the key wasn't found.

Here is the function:

```
public static HashMap<String, Object> getHashMap(HashMap<String, 
                                      Object> map, String key)
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     if (entry.getValue().getClass().getName() == "java.util.HashMap") {
         if (entry.getKey() == key) 
          return (HashMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
         return getHashMap((HashMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue(), key);
     }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It only works for the first item.  How do I traverse a Hashmap of HashMaps?  What is a better approach?

Comment: If you want to check if an object is a `HashMap`, use `object instanceof HashMap`... comparing the class name like that is a very bad idea, especially since you're doing it wrong (need to use `equals`). Even then, you shouldn't care if something is a `HashMap` specifically... it should be enough that it implements `Map`.

Comment: Thank you for the advices. I modified it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the value immediately here:

```
return getHashMap((HashMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue(), key);
```

you want to first check if it is not `null`, and return it only then. Otherwise you should just continue searching:

```
HashMap<String, Object> result = getHashMap((HashMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue(), key);
if (result != null)
  return result;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I hadn't see that point. Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

For one, don't use `==` for Strings. Instead use the equals method.

For another, I prefer to do instanceof such as `if (myObject instanceof java.util.Map) { ... }` this way your map doesn't have to be a HashMap if later you decide to change it.

Comment: To explain this: using == on a pair of strings checks whether or not they are the same object in memory.  Using a.equals(b) checks whether strings a and b contain the exact same characters.  For most string comparisons, you want .equals

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. Try use `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> main` for your 'outer' HashMap, then you'll search for `key`:

```
Object value = main.get(key);
if (value == null) {
    for (HashMap<String, Object> inner : main.values()) {
        value = inner.get(key);
        if (value != null) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Casablanca's answer works pretty well. Thank you for your answer as well.